# Adding two epoch millseconds in C++

Tags: c++, epoch

My goal is to determine expiry of an item to when it was acquired(bought) and when it is sold.There is a TTL value associated with each of the item.

I am doing following :

```
time_t currentSellingTime;
long currentSystemTime = time(&currentSellingTime); // this gives me epoch millisec of now()

long TTL = <some_value>L;
long BuyingTime = <some_value> // this is also in epoch millsec


if(currentSystemTime >  TTL+BuyingTime))
{
//throw exception 
// item is expired
}
```

My question is how to sum two epoch millisec and compare it with another epoch millsec in C++

Comment: You probably don't want to add them. That doesn't really mean anything. Take the difference.

Comment: @PeterWood He's adding (or intends to add) a TTL (time to live) to a timestamp, so it's probably a safe operation for the years to come, but there are other issues with his program imo

Comment: Also, adding them will probably cause an integer overflow. Integers can roughly store about 68 years. At the moment we are 43 years since the epoch so adding them together will give 86, which is equivalent to 18 years (modulo 68).

Answer (score 1):

There may be some misconceptions on how [`time()` works](http://linux.die.net/man/2/time):

1. epoch time as given by `time()` is expressed in seconds, not millseconds
2. time returns the current time value and can optionally set current time in the variable given as its sole argument.  This means that

   long currentSystemTime = time(&currentSellingTime);

will set both `currentSystemTime` and `currentSellingTime` to the current time, and that's probably not what you intend to do...  You should probably do

```
long currentSystemTime = time(NULL);
```

or

```
time(&currentSellingTime);
```

but the "double form" you are using is quite suspicious.  For completeness' sake the [MS Help reference for time()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! I made that change. But For my input set, its going into the if loop which should not be correct . Input : TTL = 1000000 , currentSystemTime-1372155260 ,currentBuyingTime-1372155245 . In this input , it should not enter the if loop but it is.

Comment: double form does  work but I agree its not the correct practice. I have corrected it.

Comment: @TopCoder of course it "works" but using 1 call to set two variables looks a bit odd and may indicate a logic flaw...  Also, in your comment you're using `currentBuyingTime` and in the code sample `BuyingTime`.  Lastly, `if` is not a loop...

Answer (score 0):

You want to use another function, as as previously pointed out, `time()` returns seconds. Try:

```
#include <time.h>


long current_time() {
    struct timespec t;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &t);

    return t.tv.sec * 1000l + t.tv_nsec / 1000000l;
}
```

Your code should work then. This approach is also POSIX compatible. Example usage:

```
const long TTL = 100;
long start_time = current_time();

while (!(current_time() > start_time + TTL))
{
    // do the stuff that can expire
}
```

note: I know that the condition in the  `while` loop can be constructed differently, but this way it is more like "until not expired".